# Markdown editor with tables

Tags: editor, markdown, wmd-markdown

Is there any client-side markdown editor that could work with tables? I just need something like Stack Overflow's editor or markdownDeep -- both of those are great. But these editors doesn't let me customize tables, like Dreamweaver does it with HTML tables.

Comment: Markdown tables are not HTML tables and never will because the later are too complex to specify in a pure readable markdown format. Thats why even in 2019 you need to be lucky to find an editor that just does the simple things.

Answer (score 5):

Typora is a very promising MarkDown editor : https://typora.io/

Tables support is very good for creation or edition, as long as many other features.

It is using GitHub Flavored Markdown ... which is good, but cannot produce CommonMark only for now.

Answer (score 1):

[Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra) has support for [tables](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table), however that's PHP only.

There is, however, a [JavaScript Markdown Extra library](https://github.com/tanakahisateru/js-markdown-extra) on Github, based on the PHP version.

Comment: I didn't mean server parser. All i need is the wmd-like markdown editor, that support tables.

Comment: The second paragraph in my answer has a link to a JavaScript (**client side**) Markdown Extra parser and, considering Markdown Extra supports tables, that's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean an markdown editor. The instrument, thats help me to create tables (like stackoverflow provides "bold" or "italic" buttons) without painting it. Something like dreamweaver do with html tables (generate tags and helps to resize the cells).

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding. In that case, I'm no help :( I'll delete my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**[Mark Text](https://github.com/marktext/marktext)** is a Markdown editor for Mac. It is a concise text editor, dedicated to improving your editing efficiency, enabling you to enjoy pleasure when you finish documents, novels and conference notes easily.

It supports tables and other GFM syntax.

[Here is what Mark Text looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abs42.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[Nwotable](https://nwotable.herokuapp.com/app/) is a Progressive Web App to edit markdown (Github Flavored).
So it support :

- Tables
- Emojis
- Indefinitely nestable tags

For more info or check the source code --> [here](https://github.com/Nergel3/Nwotable).